# CDI Portable Extension for Struts 1.3?

Tags: struts, cdi

here's an idea i have been playing with for a while.

is it possible to mix CDI and Struts 1.3 ?

E.g. via a CDI Portable Extension..?

As for 'why', there are still a few projects 'out there' which are stuck on an old stack and don't have the option to switch to struts 2..

Just throwing it out there, i'm interested in your ideas =)

greetings from germany

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just committed my library to github, called **struts-cdi**. You should check it out.

https://github.com/reegnz/struts-cdi

It only works with Struts Actions for now, and not with ActionForms. If the need arises, I will also  try to do container managed ActionForms. :^)

Comment: damn that's nice, this is basically what I was thinking about doing after doing some digging around in the struts 1 documentation, looking for a place to hook the cdi provider into.. 
i definitely will give this a try!

Comment: well i just threw this into a fairly huge project and it failed with an exception "weld argument bean may not be null" 
after your post i already forked your github repository, i will dig into this in the coming days and will keep you posted ;)

Comment: Even though the information you have given is very vague, I believe it might be an issue with the BeanLookup.
More precisely the action to be instantiated is not managed by CDI, therefore the Bean returned by CDI is null, and thus the BeanManager#getReference method is throwing the exception.
The CDI validation on deployment is not seeing this, since you do not inject those actions anywhere, so it doesn't need to check if they are registered or not.

tl;dr: Do not forget to add beans.xml to the archives your actions are in (WEB-INF for war, META-INF for jar files).

Comment: *cough* well that's embarrassing considering i am an active JEE Developer.. damn beans.xml file was missing again (so easy to forget that thing)
your extension works like a breeze! i just successfully tested the usage of injection, producers and observers in a struts action. many many many thanks, now i finally got a good point to sell some migration efforts to management =D this library is exactly what i was looking for. #

Answer (score 0):

[Stripes Injection Enricher](https://code.google.com/p/stripes-ejb3/) satisfies injection points specified declaratively using standard Java EE annotations (`@EJB`, `@Inject` and `@Resource`).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that one. Did I get it right that stripes is some sort of wrapper around struts?

Comment: It was based on Struts, but it's different. Inject resources in Struts 1.x is not possible because the _actions_ are not **managed** by the _container_ but by a _servlet_, in this case the `org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet`.